# Listing packages linked with react-native link

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I need to be able to see which packages I have linked with `react-native link <dependency-name>` to write some documentation for other devs on my team.

I didn't previously document every package I linked because I wanted to test packages before documenting that they were being used, so I didn't leave incorrect information in my documentation.

I have already run `react-native link --help` which doesn't list any way to do this. Is the only way to find linked libraries to look at the `.gradle` or `podfile`?

Answer (score 2):

Android can be found in '`Mainapplication.java`' file.

```java
    @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new RNModule(), 
            ....            //your install native module list
        );
    }
```

In case of iOS, you can check in your `podfile`.

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
...
pod 'RNModule', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-module'
```

And I don't recommend this method, but if you run '`react-natvie link`', you will see that you link all the modules you added.

Comment: What u described is just great! CTRL + F and one is great to go